# Creation of State of Israel and birth of Abraham - 1948

Tags: history, number, calendar, avot-patriarch-fathers, state-of-israel

According to the Jewish calendar, Abraham was born on the year 1948.

The state of Israel was declared in 1948 according to the secular calendar.

Is there any significance to this or is it just coincidence.

Comment: I would think it is only a coincidence, as it involves two different calendar systems.

Comment: @Dennis right but one God runs the world.

Comment: What sort of evidence are you looking for?

Comment: If people would count in [base twelve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duodecimal) instead of base ten, then a [thousand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1728_(number)) would be the cube of twelve, or 1728. Adding the eighth part to it, we have 9/8 x 1728 = 1944. If you're wondering why this might be even remotely relevant, please see my answer on [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75610) question.

Comment: Yeah, it's easy to remember that way...

Answer (score 7):

**Coincidence.**

The bible does not explicitly state the year in which Abraham was born, and as such, there have been disagreements about the calculations of the biblical years.  Thus, it is unclear if Abraham was actually born in the year 1948 from Creation.

The current civil calendar is the Gregorian Calendar, based on the Julian Calendar, which was created in 45 B.C.E.  Thus, according to the original calendar, the State of Israel was established in `1948 + 45 = 1993.`  However, in the  sixth-century, a Christian scholar named Dionysius Exiguus did some research regarding the birth of Jesus, and reset the calendar to its current numbering system.  (As an aside, modern scholars generally believe that Jesus was born some years before "year 1".)

Even if it is not a coincidence, there does not appear to be any significance to these dates.  And even if there was, and God indeed chose these dates, there are many more significant dates He could have chosen, such as the dates when the Israelites entered the Land of Israel, or were given the Torah at Mt Sinai, or the building of the Temple, etc.

Comment: You have confused the Julian CALENDAR with the Christian ERA. There never was any era that counted years from 45 BCE. The Romans counted their years from the suppposed date of the foundation of Rome.

Answer (score 2):

Among Jews of a more mystical hashkafa, such as chassidim and many others, there is no such thing as a coincidence. This view -- that everything happens for a reason -- was strongly stated by the Baal Shem Tov, but is also discernible in previous sources (such as Rabbi Akiva's "Gamzu L'Tovah" story in the Gemara, and statements by rabbis such as Rabbeinu Bachya and R' Avraham ben Rambam.)

In addition, the more specific idea that Hashem send us "hints" is also found in rabbinic literature (For example, "Think about the thoughts, words and deeds that God sends you each day in order to understand His hints to you to draw closer to Him at every moment." Likutey Moharan I, 54.)

To more rationalist Jews, of course, the 1948 parallelism between the founding of modern Israel and Avraham Avinu's birth would be nothing more than a coincidence.

More mystically-inclined Jews could argue that it does in fact have a meaning. Since Hashem first promised the Land of Israel to Avraham, it may be a sign that the creation of the state is the fulfillment of His promise that the Jews would inherit the land.

The fact that 1948 is on the Christian calendar may pose difficulty to some, who may have trouble understanding why G-d would send messages through another religion's calendar. Yet logically, since G-d is all-powerful, it is not beyond His power to send subtle messages to Jews through another religion's calendar.

Perhaps the use of the Christian calendar was meant to hint that the mistreatment that Jews had suffered at the hands of Christians for 2000 years, culminating in the Holocaust, was now coming to an end, as the Jews returned to their divinely-promised homeland. In addition, the use of the Christian calendar could have been meant to hint to Christians that Hashem is still honoring His promises to the Jewish people, which could potentially induce Christians to become less anti-Semitic or more supportive of Israel.

Comment: Any British Jew will be able to tell you why remember amalek is on page 1066 of the arts roll chumash

Comment: *why G-d would send messages through another religion's calendar* - Even if He would have used the Jewish calendar, it would technically still have been *another religion's calendar*, inasmuch as Biblical Jews borrowed theirs from the surrounding cultures or civilizations of their time: Egyptians (New Year in [Tishri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thout)), Babylonians (New Year in [Nisan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_calendar); lunar based), and [Greeks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meton_of_Athens) (19-year [Metonic cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonic_cycle)).

Answer (score 0):

Reading the Bible literally, Genesis 9:28 explains that after the flood (which occurred in 1656), Noah lived for 350 years. Abraham was born in 1948. This is also the date for the modern state of Israel. Coincidence? Actually, the Bible never explicitly states the date of Abraham’s birth.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is a coincidence (Megillat Esther teaches us that there are no coincidences). As per Daniel's vision in 536 BCE, Israel's *Seven Times Punishment* which God had warned about in Vayikra 26:28, terminated in 1948 (see Dan 12:1, 5–7).

Since a *time* equals 360 years in Torah eschatology, the period given in Dan 12:7 equals **1,260 years** (*a time, times, and a half = 360 years + 720 years + 180 years = 1,260 years*). But since the context provides TWO angels and TWO raised hands, the time span needs to be doubled (*1,260 years + 1,260 years = **2,520 years***). Adding the equivalent solar years to 536 BCE takes us to 1948:

**-536 + 2,483.78 years = 1948**

In 1948 God fulfilled the UNCONDITIONAL Abrahamic Covenant and brought Israel (back) into her homeland; the year marked the end of *Israel's Seven Times Punishment* which had commenced AFTER the Babylonian exile (because she had never repented).

Answer (score -6):

It is no coincidence. The Modern Jewish Calendar with its formal rules was set by Maimonides in 1178 CE. The Epoch was set at October 7 3761 BCE whereas the creation was September 11 3760, which is 339 days earlier.

The Talmudic rabbis are and have been for many centuries, devoted to Gematria and subjectively significant numerical concordances. This is because such research is abundantly fruitful.

Euler's number e = 2.71828 truncated to 5 decimals.
The magic number PI/6 = 0.5236 rounded to 4 decimals.

71828 MOD 5236 = 3760, the year of creation.
The first integer which indexes itself in the decimals of e = 2543 = Prime(372)
KABALLAH(Bar Nafli) = 372, where Bar Nafli (Son of the Fallen One) is a name for the Jewish Messiah.

I suspect that an individual purporting to be this figure will be ritually announced on May 7 2018. The date code here is 572 which is Kaballah for "Son of Sinfulness". This is 5778 in the Hebrew Calendar.

5778 MOD 2701 = 376 = Kaballah(Security for the Jews) and 2701 is the number of creation from the first verse of The Torah

The standard latin Gematria for "The Torah" is again 572, date code of the messianic day.
THis is also the Latin Gematria for "Monotheism".

You might feel that mixing Hebrew and Latin Gematria is a no-no until you realise that 572 = 22*26 the product of the numbers of letters in these two alphabets.

This will be very bad news for non Jews, such as myself.

Comment: Do you have sources for any of this?

Comment: @Scimonster well, math is math, so stating mathematical facts (such as the mod calculations and the gematriot) doesn't really *require* a source, but stating that the math is relevant and not a coincidence without a source is... iffy. (I guess it depends on how strongly you lean on the principle of hashgocha pratis/klalis?)